# Var in scala not reassigning correctly

Tags: scala

I have an output as an ArrayList from a Java Function
To which I am applying a map to convert all internal elements in Array from ArrayList to an Array

While doing the conversion on a single line seems to be working fine but reassigning to var seems to create a problem and gives an error

This seems to work fine

```
var rowList = readerTask.execute().get().asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[Any]].toArray().map(x => x.asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[Any]].toArray())
  

rowList.length should equal(3)

rowList(0)(0) should equal(1)
```

Where as

```
var rowList = readerTask.execute().get().asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[Any]].toArray()
rowList = rowList.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[Any]].toArray())

rowList.length should equal(3)

rowList(0)(0) should equal(1)
```

Seems to give me an error in IntelliJ

```
'AnyRef' does not take parameter at this `rowList(0)(0) should equal(1)`
```

I am fairly new to Scala, and don't see what must be wrong
as I am simply applying a map on a new line

Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `rowList` has a different type in the two versions of the code.

If you do not supply a type for a variable, Scala will infer the type from the value used to initialise it.

In the first case the type of `rowList` is inferred to be `Array[Array[Any]]` because that is the type of the whole expression.

In the second case the type of `rowList` is inferred to be `Array[Any]` because that is the type of the first part of the expression. The following assignment works because `Array[Array[Any]]` is compatible with `Array[Any]` so there is no error. But clearly you cannot double index into `Array[Any]` so the test fails.

More generally, `Any`, `asInstanceOf`, and `var` are best avoided; there are almost always ways to avoid using them and avoiding them usually results in better code.

Comment: That makes sense because the types are different during assignment. Then my problem boils down to converting from type Any to Array[Array[Any]] or testing whether the values match by indexing them in a different way. What should be my approach towards it. Is there a better way to achieve that.

Comment: Using `match` (or in this case `collect`) is a better approach, but would need to know that actual types you are starting with, so perhaps put this in a separate question.